# Windows remote desktop session host high availability login

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, round-robin

I had Windows Terminal Server (WS2012 Standard R2), where everything worked as expected. After this I installed 3 more servers and did high availability with 2 connection brokers and 2 session hosts servers, so 4 servers in total now. I have round robin DNS, fifth server for SQL and high availability of connection brokers. I have those questions :

- 1.If I try to connect to round robin DNS via classic Windows RDP, I am getting error "Remote logins are currently disabled". This only works if I have connection broker servers in session host pool of collection but I do not want use CB servers for remote logins
- 2.If I try to connect to round robin DNS via IE (work resources), I see login page and can not succefully login with no error message. When I click on "sign in", I just see same page with no credentials filled.

  I can connect to session host servers RDP via IE and IP adress of connection broker (not RR DNS) if no apps are published. If some apps are published, I can run them from session host servers but can not see icon for remote desktop login.
- 3.Is there any possibility to have true fail-over on session hosts? If I disconnect one session host server from network, I can not login to another session host server and session which exists on disconnected session host over I have user mapping disks on another sever. I do not believe, that this is possible, so main questions are first and second one.
- 4.Is it possible to use same session servers for two collections? One for RDP and second for published apps? Seems not...

I tried to google a lot about it but no information helped.